# python function call by using tuple

Tags: python, function

I am writing code utilizing tuple for function call

```
def get_apple():
    print('you got an apple.')

def get_pear():
    print('you got a pear.')

fruits = (get_apple, get_pear)

print('0. apple\n1. pear')
s = eval(input('which one : '))

fruits[s]()
```

But once I execute this script, it only returns "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable" on "fruitss".

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: return some value from `get_apple` and `get_pear`.

Comment: I don't get an error using python 3.6

Comment: Not reproducible.  Please provide a [mcve].  Also you should avoid `eval` at all cost because it's unsafe.  Just use `int(input('which one : '))`.  For example try type `exit()` when prompted for input.

Comment: This code works, your error would trigger on `get_apple[s]`, but that ain't the case

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Get rid of it; you *know* you want `s` to be an `int`, so use `int(input(...))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just do this:

```
def get_apple():
    print('you got an apple.')

def get_pear():
    print('you got a pear.')

fruits = (get_apple, get_pear)

n = int(input('0. apple\n1. pear'))

fruits[n]()
```

there is no need for `eval`.

you'd have to check for non-integer input of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_apple():
    print('you got an apple.')

def get_pear():
    print('you got a pear.')

fruits = (get_apple, get_pear)

print('0. apple\n1. pear')
s = eval(str(input('which one : ')))

fruits[s]()
```

This code worked in both python 2.7.5 and python 3.7.1.

`eval()` takes input string as input . Hence converting input to `str`.